# How does ruby console work?

Tags: ruby

When I call irb, this is what I have to do:

```
>irb
irb(main):001:0>load "~/ruby/function.rb" 
irb(main):002:0>function(variable) { |x| printf("result: %s\n",x.inspect) }
```

How does irb extract `x`'s value? How should I write a function so that irb can take `x`? I tried

```
def function (a)
  a
end
```

I also tried

```
def function (a)
  puts a
end
```

Neither of these works. They only output whatever I input.

```
result : %s\n" part does not get output on irb console.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside function.rb:

```
def function(variable) 
  yield variable
end
```

On your console:

```
irb >>load "~/ruby/function.rb"
irb >>function(variable) { |x| printf("result: %s\n",x.inspect) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(a)
  puts "result: %s\n" % a.inspect
end
```

Or you could simply do:

```
def function(a)
  puts "result: #{a.inspect}\n"
end
```

Comment: well that's just how we write program when you simply load ruby file in following way right?
> ruby function.rb

what I need is 
> irb
>>load "~/ruby/function.rb"
>>function (a) { |x| printf("result: %s\n",x.inspect) }